# How to make Frame expand when the content expands in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

As per the title, i have a label inside a frame, both set to fill and expand and its inside a Grid, wanted to know if its possible to expand automatically when the content of the label text goes to the next line

```
<Frame Grid.Row="1" 
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               Margin="15,25,15,10"
               CornerRadius="25"
               Padding="10"
               HasShadow="False"
               BorderColor="Transparent"
               BackgroundColor="White">

            <Label x:Name="QuestionLabel" 
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                   Style="{x:StaticResource LabelTitleBold}"
                   Text="{Binding Question}" 
                   TextColor="{x:StaticResource Primary}"/>
        </Frame>
```

This is what i've done, any inputs would be deeply appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is try setting the height of Row in RowDefinition of the Grid to Auto. This might help.

```
<RowDefinition Height="auto" />
```

Let me know